# express-session y sessionID - Duracion

Tags: nodejs, express, express-session

Estoy empezando en nodejs, vengo de php, estaba probando express-session y tengo una duda..

¿Como puedo hacer para que sessionID dure x tiempo y no me cambie la id cada vez que refresco la pagina?

```html
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}))
```

He intentado usando `maxAge` con una hora, dura más pero no una:

```
hora.app.use(session({

  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: {  maxAge: 60000 }
}))
```